# Index error when trying to compare values in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find the remainder of each number in a list that is equal to one, but the problem is I get an index error

Here I compare the current item in the list to the next one:

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

sorted_number = sorted(numbers)

for index, num in enumerate(sorted_number):
    if sorted_number[index + 1] % sorted_number[index] == 1:
        print(index, num)
```

Comment: Please include full error and your list if possible.

Comment: index error is exactly what it means.
you're enumerating through your full set of lists (that means going from 0 to len(sorted_number)-1.
you have no element on position len(sorted_number).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get to the last element of `sorted_number`, the call `sorted_number[index + 1]` is out of bounds. You can avoid this by only iterating to the second to last number in the list:

```
for index, num in enumerate(sorted_number[:-1]):
    if sorted_number[index + 1] % sorted_number[index] == 1:
        print(index, num)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting index error because the index + 1 is greater than sorted_number lengh, so you need to add a check for that case

```
for index, num in enumerate(sorted_number):
    if index < len(sorted_number) - 1:
        if sorted_number[index + 1] % sorted_number[index] == 1:
            print(index, num)
```